# Generate unique string ID using a string in PostgreSQL functions

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I need to generate unique id based on another column value for each record being inserted into a table.

Let's say, I have a table EG_TAB (ID, STRING). ID should be generated based on the STRING and also should satisfy the below conditions

1. should be unique (should not be in the table already)
2. should be generated from the input STRING.
3. should be 8 characters length.
4. If STRING has single word, then take the first four characters and suffix random numbers to the end.
5. If STRING has multiple words, then take the first character from each of the words, then fill the remaining characters with the random numbers.

Is this possible in PostgreSQL functions?

Comment: Why not simply use a sequence for the `ID`? Or if it should be something "random", use a `uuid`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I cannot go with sequence or UUID as the id will be given to the users. To make it easy to remember, the id is generated from the user input.

Comment: What's easier to remember than a number?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ID should be 8 char length:-). It will be hard to remember a number with 8 digits.

Comment: `create sequence tab_id_seq start with 10000000 maxvalue 99999999`

Comment: From a database perspective, this is just a bad idea. Eight characters doesn't allow for very many combinations to begin with, and you're limiting that even further by trying to make the characters "meaningful". Let the users choose a pass-phrase, then store a (salted) hash of that pass-phrase as a data column that has an integer ID column assigned to it. The user can use the pass-phrase, and the database can use the ID column.

Comment: If id is the primary key, then any sane hashfunction(id) would suffice. You don't even need the string, since it is functionally dependent on id. -->> xy problem